# Substitute Quinoa Flour to All-Purpose Flour

Tags: substitutions, flour, quinoa

If the recipe calls for 1 cup All Purpose Flour, how many cups of Quinoa flour should I use to completely replace All-Purpose flour?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to make? You can't directly substitute quinoa flour for all purpose flour for many recipes.

Comment: This question cannot be answered in the general case.   Wheat flour is very complex, with aspects of its behavior in recipes deriving from both its starch content, and from its unique protein content which forms gluten.  To get some sort of reasonable answer on how to make substitutions, you will need to provide context of what kind of recipe, and what constraints you have for how to do the substitution.  It is rare that a single alternate product will completely replace wheat flour.  Often, you are better off finding recipes designed for your product of choice.

Comment: Further to other comments, a huge number of flour-based recipes - quite possibly the *majority* of them - rely *specifically* on gluten, which won't form at all with quinoa flour, so there *is no* correct substitution. It is certainly possible to make (or approximate) many of these dishes with non-wheat flours, or even totally gluten-free, but rarely with straight substitutions; typically these involve a number of other changes to the recipe.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace 100% of gluten containing flour in a recipe, you will probably need to vary the amounts of the other ingredients, the cooking time and the cooking temperature. It doesn’t behave the same as gluten containing flours in the oven.

Every recipe is different, but some very general rules of thumb are (for which there are probably just as many exceptions – I know, it's so annoying. But look on the bright side: Grain and gluten free living will certainly keep your creative side ticking):

- Reduce the cooking time
- Reduce the cooking temperature
- Increase the amount of moisture in the recipe
- Increase or add more binding agent (such as eggs). The lack of gluten can mean the final result doesn’t hold together as well. This rule is the least likely to be true, but it’s worth keeping in mind if your results are less than amazing.